# Does the GOGS Docker Container run an SSH Daemon?

Tags: docker, gogs

I'm wondering whether the [GOGS Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/gogs/gogs/) is also running an the OpenSSH daemon inside the container?

Comment: You just need to check the Dockerfile, do you see Ssh installed, or does the line FROM show an image coming with Ssh? Anyway you can add it and `docker commit` the new image

Comment: You should read this post wrote by a Docker engineer: https://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/23/docker-ssh-considered-evil/

Comment: Yes I am aware of the post and it's a good one.  Gogs uses S6 I believe to run multiple processes, however I'm still getting up to speed on S6, thus I'm looking insight into how to interpret the Gogs docker build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - the [Gogs Docker Container](https://github.com/gogits/gogs/tree/master/docker) runs the openssh daemon.

To see this first start the gogs docker container with the name `gogs` and then run `docker top gogs`.  This will display a table showing all the processes running in the gogs container.

Answer (score 0):

The [gogs container Dockerfile](https://github.com/gogits/gogs/blob/master/Dockerfile) uses [alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine/), which itself does not include Openssh.

See this [Dockerfile](https://github.com/chamunks/alpine-openssh/blob/master/Dockerfile) as an example of adding openssh on top of alpine.